# Sort records based on association (has_many through) column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

I am facing an issue where I have to sort jobs on the basis of min time_out field of job_trade_contractors. There is a possibility that the time_out field can be nil for job_trade_contractors. I have associations like:

1: job.rb

```
has_many :job_trades, dependent: :destroy
has_many :job_trade_contractors, through: :job_trades
```

2: job_trade.rb

```
has_many :job_trade_contractors, dependent: :destroy
```

3: job_trade_contractors.rb

```
belongs_to :job_trade, touch: true
```

Currently, I am applying sort on jobs via this code:

```
Job.left_joins(:job_trade_contractors).order("job_trade_contractors.time_out asc")
```

It sorts jobs on the basis of time_out correctly but what I need is sorting on the minimum time_out values job_trade_contractors belong to a particular job.

Let's say we have 2 jobs that have 5 job_trade_contractors each. We will need to sort jobs based on the minimum time_out values among the associated job_trade_contractors.

Example
Jobs

`j1 ->
  1: job_trade_contractor ->
   id: 1
   time_out: 21-01-2020
  2: job_trade_contractor ->
    id: 2
    time_out: 20-01-2020
  3: job_trade_contractor ->
    id: 3
    time_out: 11-01-2020
  4: job_trade_contractor ->
    id: 4
    time_out: 19-01-2020
  5: job_trade_contractor ->
    id: 5
    time_out: 23-01-2020`

`j2 ->
  1: job_trade_contractor ->
   id: 1
   time_out: 21-01-2020
  2: job_trade_contractor ->
    id: 2
    time_out: 20-01-2020
  3: job_trade_contractor ->
    id: 3
    time_out: 11-01-2020
  4: job_trade_contractor ->
    id: 4
    time_out: 10-01-2020
  5: job_trade_contractor ->
    id: 5
    time_out: 25-01-2020`

Result should be

j2 
j1

because we have job_trade_contractor with time_out value: 10-01-2020 as min in j2
and 11-01-2020 in j1

Answer (score 0):

We can implement the sort in the following way, this might be helpful for you,

```
has_many :job_trade_contractors, through: :job_trades, order: 'job_trade_contractors.time_out'
```

or

```
has_many :job_trade_contractors, ->  { order(time_out: :asc) }, through: :job_trades
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But i dont want to make any changes in associations. I would like to have a sql query or something

Answer (score 0):

```
Job.joins(job_trades: :job_trade_contractors).order('job_trade_contractors.time_out').uniq
```